# Prevent duplicate key usage

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database is Postgresql. For an simplified example I will insert measurement data in various tables. Example DDL for one example table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
measurement
(
    id_meas BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id_meas)
);
```

The process of inserting data currently works like this:

1. Select max id value from table
2. Increment id value
3. Insert next data row using incremented id value

This works as long as there is only one client inserting data. But what if there are > 1 client's inserting so that two clients may select 567 as max id value and both increment this to 568 as next id value to insert. In that case the second client executing the insert command will receive an duplicate key error. Is there a way to prevent those errors other than re-executing the insertion process after an error occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `serial` column:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    id_meas bigserial primary key,
    ...
);
```

`bigserial` is a `bigint` that auto-increments (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)).  You can also just use `serial` if an `int` is big enough.

This puts the database in charge of incrementing the value, rather than the application.  You are guaranteed that race conditions will not result in the same value in different records.  It is possible that gaps in the value will appear under some circumstances.

Comment: Ok, gaps shouldn't be a problem here, but what if I need the key value in order to store it in some other tables as foreign key reference? Is there a way to return the database generated serial value used for inserts, so that every client will know the generated id for his own particular `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I might use a `returning` clause with a CTE, for instance.